# Nesting "get" request under a "get" with lambda in Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a get request which looks like this and works fine:

```
get ':slug', :to => "countries#show", 
  :constraints => lambda { |r| 
                    Country.find_by_slug(r.params[:slug]).present? }, as: :country
```

This makes urls like `site.com/japan` work fine.

Although the structure does not look nice, I am using it because there's a lot of legacy routes that are opening under root URL.

Anyway,

I need to nest additional resources under cities:

```
resources :places, only: :show
```

To enable urls such as: `site.com/japan/tv-tower`

I tried going with something like:

```
constraints lambda { |request| 
  Country.find_by_slug(request.params[:slug]).present? } do
    resources places, only: :show
end
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: I think the issue is that the expression ':slug' only matches when there is no slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the result is not to have japan/places/tv-tower -- which is what you get if you don't set the path and the reason you aren't getting a valid route now.

I would forget about the :slug and just use resources for countries, even if it's only show, this will make sure you still have a valid route name and route for just the country with no place listed.

```
resources :countries, only: [:show], path: '', :constraints => proc { |req| Country.find_by_slug(req.params[:country_id].nil? ? req.params[:id] : req.params[:country_id])  } do
  resources :places, path: ''
end
```

That will leave you with routes that look like:

```
       country_places GET    /:country_id(.:format)           places#index
                      POST   /:country_id(.:format)           places#create
    new_country_place GET    /:country_id/new(.:format)       places#new
   edit_country_place GET    /:country_id/:id/edit(.:format)  places#edit
        country_place GET    /:country_id/:id(.:format)       places#show
                      PATCH  /:country_id/:id(.:format)       places#update
                      PUT    /:country_id/:id(.:format)       places#update
                      DELETE /:country_id/:id(.:format)       places#destroy
              country GET    /:id(.:format)                   countries#show
```